# Browserify: override package and use different main file

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

Browserify's [`"browser"` field](https://github.com/substack/browserify-handbook#browser-field) in the `package.json` seems overloaded and I can't figure out a way to get around this issue

How would I shim several packages not necessary in the browser (such as `ws` and `canvas`) while also changing the `"main"` file for `browserify`'s use

I was hoping something like this would work

```
{
    "browser": {
       "ws": "./src/browser/ws-shim",
       "main": "./src/BrowserVersion"
    }
}
```

**[src/browser/ws-shim](https://github.com/RobotWebTools/roslibjs/blob/develop/src/util/shim/WebSocket.js)**

```
module.exports = global.WebSocket;
```

[Repository in question](https://github.com/RobotWebTools/roslibjs) has some specific Node functionality such as services over `TCP` and `stream` support which won't make sense in the browser. Meanwhile, we use node ports of several browser APIs to share code between the `Node` and `Browserify`ied versions of the lib

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `browser` key to map to your main file.

```
{
    "browser": "./src/browserIndex.js"
}
```

Then use the [aliasify](https://github.com/benbria/aliasify) transform to map the rest of your  dependencies.

```
{
    "browserify": {
        "transform": [ "aliasify" ]
    },
    "aliasify": {
        "aliases": {
            "ws": "./src/browser/ws-shim"
        }
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "aliasify": "^1.4.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I'll give that a try, would aliasify have to be a dependency of the project?

Comment: Yes, I added that to my example

Comment: I'm having no luck with that configuration https://gist.github.com/megawac/e5ecbffd336557aff456 (https://github.com/megawac/roslibjs/tree/browserify)

Comment: Seems to be a bug in aliasify. If you add `fromSourceFileDir: true` to `aliasify.js` it works fine. The problem is that it's looking in your root `package.json` instead of the one for the `roslibjs` package. Maybe there is an alternative transformer.

Comment: Nice find! Are you planning to make a PR to [aliasify](https://github.com/benbria/aliasify)?